# Which vector bundles are injective?

Tags: differential-geometry, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

In the additive category of vector bundles over a fixed manifold, which are the injective objects? Are there enough injectives?

Comment: I don't know the answer, and sorry for the trivial remark but are you sure that vector bundles over a fixed manifold form an abelian category ? You probably need to specify something about the morphisms right ?

Comment: @N.H. Oh, right. Not every morphism will have a kernel. Possibly I need to take only morphisms with constant index or something?

Comment: Yes I was thinking to this too. Best would be to take coherent sheaf I think, because I didn't know about vector bundle and a quick googling made me think there are no reasonable way of defining a structure of an abelian category on the category of vector bundle. Here is a thread on mathoverflow : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/107101/is-the-category-of-vector-bundles-over-a-topological-space-abelian

Comment: @N.H. thanks for your remark. I think the question still makes sense, though.

Comment: Yes written this way this make sense, so maybe I can delete my comment ?

Comment: I'd leave it, it was helpful, and maybe other people will wonder why I'm not considering an abelian category.